# Stop any event listener on parent component Angular 6+

Tags: angular

Designing a component which takes html button

my-button.html

```
<button type="config.type", [disable]="config.disable">
 ....lot of other stuffs 
</button>
```

somewhere else in the app - 
home.component.html

```
<my-button [config]="config" (click)="handleClick()"></my-button>
```

Now, if someone attach a `(click)="handleClick()"` on `my-button`, click happens even if child html button is disabled. How can I stop this behavior from Child?

Comment: so do you want your component to completely ignore clicks regardless if its attached?

Comment: not exactly. Ignore until `config.disable` is true. Want to definitely handle the logic in my-component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I would probably think of leveraging "pointer-events" attribute ("auto" / "none"). Something like this:

```
  <my-button (click)="clickMe()" [style.pointer-events]="config.disable">
    <button ion-button>Hi</button>
  </my-button>
```

Where config.disable is either "auto" or "none";

Or if you need to stick to boolean:

```
  <my-button (click)="clickMe()" [style.pointer-events]="config.disable? 'none':'auto'">
    <button ion-button>Hi</button>
  </my-button>
```

Comment: In the above case, consumer of my-button has to set style attr. Since my-button is in shared space and there could be many consumers, it can never be forced. do we have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in your ts or html file

### Solution 1

```
<my-button [config]="config" (click)="config.disable ? return false : handleClick()"></my-button>
```

### Solution 2

### in html

```
<my-button [config]="config" (click)="handleClick(config.disable)"></my-button>
```

### ts

```
handleClick(disabled){
   if(disabled){
      return;
   }else{
     //execute rest of the codes here ...
   }
}
```

### Solution 3

If you want to handle the click event in your component then you can use `HostListener`

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) 
  onClick(e) {
    if(someCondition){  //If disabled
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since my-button is in shared space and there could be many consumers, it can never be forced. do we have any other solution? Need control from my-button.ts file to stop click event in the consumer's code. some mechanism to remove (click) event listener.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more cause I am not sure I understand the context? what is "shared space"? means multiple users could either "attach" listener or not?

Comment: Updated the answer with `Solution 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopPropagation(), which will deny the propagation to the child elements.

```
handleClick(event){
   ...
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```